# How to make a <picture> element responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive, srcset

I've been struggling some hours trying to understand how the picture tag exactly works. I'm able to load different art directions at specific screen sizes using the `<picture>` tag in combination with `<srcset>` but I can't seem to find how I make these responsive.

I gave the `<picture>` element a class named `.header-img`. I tried to set media queries for the class and adjust the size of it. But when I try to set a width to `.header-img`, the width doesn't change.

Maybe an important detail, the `<picture>`element is inside a `grid`

```html
 <picture class="header-img">
                <source media="(max-width: 500px)" srcset="./assets/img/header/header-bg-sm.png">
                <source media="(max-width: 1100px)" srcset="./assets/img/header/header-bg-md.png">
                <source media="(max-width: 1300px)" srcset="./assets/img/header/header-bg-lg.png">
                <img src="./assets/img/header/header-bg-lg.png" alt="ISB header">
 </picture>
```

Any help is really really appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.header-img img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

And also, you have a **container** with property **width** of 70rem.

You should change the property width to max-width like so:

```
.container {
    max-width: 70rem;
    ...
}
```

Comment: This did the job. Thank you so much. Really appreciate it! Been struggling a long time with this 

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)